# JAVA_HOME Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, java-home

I really tried to avoid this question since there are already a lot of it. However I could just not fix to set the my terminal to the right JAVA_HOME.

First here the following outputs:

Java-Home

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Java-Version:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Maven-version:

```
mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
```

Installed-Java-Version:

```
/usr/lib/jvm$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Mär 22  2014 default-java -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Nov 19  2015 java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 26  2016 java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Mai  7  2016 java-8-oracle
```

We can see that the default java-version is set to 1.7. However the version displayed with java --version is 1.8 and maven (as well as other applications) is unable to locate any correct one.

I tried the following things:

- set JAVA_HOME in etc/environment for systemwide
- set JAVA_HOME in profile.d (jvm and jdk)
- set JAVA_HOME in a self-constructed .bashrc file in /etc/
- set JAVA_HOME in a self-constructed .bashrc file in
  usr-home-directory
- set JAVA_HOME in dot.bashrc file in /etc/
- change the default java version with config alternatives:

  :

  sudo update-alternatives --config java 
      There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  ```
    Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  * 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1075      auto mode
    1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
    2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1075      manual mode
  ```

When I set JAVA_HOME manually in the terminal it changes the variable for the session of the terminal but still does not work:

```
export JAVA_HOME=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
echo $JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
```

It would be awesome if someone can bring me some light into all of it. 
As I understood the system-wide variables are set in the /etc/environment and for the bash usually the profile.d should be loaded or I just set it in bashrc so it gets loaded each time when the terminal is initialized?

Kind regards

Comment: I actually found it! It was the .profile and .bashrc in my home directory. However be very careful when editing this. I did it first with root-permissions which led Lightdm to not work anymore because it changed the whole directory owner.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also set your PATH variable to correct java required? I guess your PATH and JAVA_HOME are pointing to different JDKs. This must be the reason for different output of java -version and echo $JAVA_HOME.

Also are you using JRE for JAVA_HOME? I think it should be JDK.

Comment: I tried to set the path like in /etc/profile and /etc/environment to PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin.I tried to let everything point at java-8-oracle(JDK)

Comment: Something must be overriding your path later on then. Did you try .bashrc or .zshrc if using zsh.

Comment: Thank you I found it in the .profile of my home-directory.